# Conditional multiplication probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> In a city, 40% of the inhabitants have one eye, 20% have black skin and 15% have both black skin and one eye. A person is randomly selected from the city.
>
> a.  If he has black skin, what is the probability he also have one eye?
>
> b.  If he has one eye, what is the probability he does not have black skin?
>
> c. If he does not have black skin,  what is the probability he has one eye?

Comment: Make a Venn diagram...

Comment: Who wrote this crappy word problem?

Comment: Sir David please can you explain better thanks

Comment: @Abdul:  Draw a Venn diagram, with a circle representing "have black skin," a circle representing "have one eye," and so on, and adjust their overlapping areas according to the problem statement...

Answer (score 0):

> In a city, 40% of the inhabitants have one eye, 20% have black skin and 15% have both black skin and one eye. A person is randomly selected from the city.

What you know: $\mathsf P(E)=0.4\\\mathsf P(B)=0.20\\\hspace{-4.5ex}\mathsf P(E\cap B)=0.15$

> a.  If he has black skin, what is the probability he also have one eye?

You seek: $\mathsf P(E\mid B)$.   Simply apply the definition of conditional probability.

> b.  If he has one eye, what is the probability he does not have black skin?
>
> c. If he does not have black skin,  what is the probability he has one eye?

And similar.  Also use the rule of a complement's probability.